# Работа с radiobutton

Tags: objective-c

Есть простой калькулятор, который умеет складывать 2 числа.
Есть кнопка Calculate по нажатию на которую 2 числа складываются и рез-т выводится в текстбокс. 
Так же есть Radio Group в нем 2 радио баттона. собственно каждая из кнопок описывается так:

```
IBOutlet NSButtonCell *firstButton;
IBOutlet NSButtonCell *seccondButton;
```

Так же есть 2 метода: первый- нажатие кнопки calculate, второй- нажатие на radio group(не уверен, что именно нажатие, поправьте если не так. Я с interface builder'a ctrl-ом перетянул стрелку от radio group в код и создал action метод вот так он выглядит - (IBAction)isSelected:(id)sender)

Так вот почему один и тот же код в методе с нажатием кнопки работает корректно, а в методе isSelected- нет
вот этот код:

```
BOOL firstRadioButtonIsOn = ([firstButton state] == NSOnState);
  BOOL seccondRadioButtonIsOn = ([seccondButton state] == NSOnState);
  if (firstRadioButtonIsOn) {
    mass.string = @"Да";
  }else if (seccondButton){
    mass.string = @"Второй";
  }
```

PS mass это просто TextView. Почему-то "второй" пишется в textview только при двойном клике на radion button. Дебаг показывает, что после первого клика на 2ой баттон(Второй:) )  [seccondButton state] возвращает "1", не пойму почему

И как вообще создавать обработчики событий, как в c#, на пример для тех же радиобатонов- isChanged?
буду благодарен тому кто отзовется. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если бы Вы выложили где нить свой проект понять было бы проще.

Comment: да, вы правы, вот он
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0KUr9piTdu1aktIZ3hpdHdoV1U/edit?usp=sharing